# I am trying to create HTML table with changeable height of one row

Tags: html, scroll, html-table, overflow

I need to create table where first row will have changeable height and second row will be fixed height.

As you can see in code I have few tables one in other, thing that I need is that first row of table with id table, have changeable height and to get scroller when window size is to small to see entire content, and second row of this table(row with button) need to be visible always. In Chrome I have wanted behavior but in Firefox and IE I don't and I need to have it in all browsers.

```
<style>
body{
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<div class="pane" style="height:100%">
    <table id="table" style="height:100%; width:100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr style="height:100%">
            <td style="height:100%">
                <div style="overflow:auto; height:100%; width:100%">
                    <div class="pane">
                        <table >
                            <tr >
                                <td >
                                    <table>
                                        <tr><td>aa</td><td>aa</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>bb</td><td>bb</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>cc</td><td>cc</td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>   
                            </tr>
                            <tr >
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tr><td>aa1</td><td>aa2</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>bb1</td><td>bb2</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>cc1</td><td>cc2</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>aa11</td><td>aa22</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>bb11</td><td>bb22</td></tr>
                                        <tr><td>cc11</td><td>cc22</td></tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="dugme"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have to respect this table structure. Any advice would be great.